# SQLAlchemy Python backend, after a few hours of no use will give a 500 error on any request, then it will work fine

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

Everytime I start my backend up and I wait for a few hours, then come back to it, on the first request I will have an error like this:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2006, "MySQL server has gone away (ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))")
```

After that everything goes back to normal.
How can I make it so the backend won't go away after a few hours of non use?

Comment: How can I test it?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to pre-ping the connection pool. In some cases the database will drop the connection and cause these errors.

See: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.create_engine.params.pool_pre_ping